# What is the correct format to do this?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME.value = 'Diwali'
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is not the correct way to ask question Lokesh. Just posting code sample does not qualify as question. How would you expect people to help you can you please edit your question and put more details.

Answer (score 0):

Lokesh, hi and welcome to the forums.

Your requirements aren't very clear. I'm guessing, but what I think you mean here is that you want all of the tables in a given schema that contain a field called 'Diwali'?

The DISTINCT is not applicable if you also specify the schema because, by definition, all table names in a single schema are unique.

For example, I ran this query - the field name that I search on is 'id'.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'id';
```

And my result is

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    -> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    -> WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'
    -> AND COLUMN_NAME = 'id';
+------------+
| TABLE_NAME |
+------------+
| august15   |
| child      |
| field_data |
| institems  |
| parent     |
| tbl_data   |
+------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If this is not your requirement, please clarify your question. Please look [here](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/) (and links within) as to how to write good questions. This forum is a great resource - help us to help you!